# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) in react while using fetch to collect data from an api

Tags: reactjs, api

I am new to react and have started it 2 days ago, so if anyone can help me with this please.

FetchApi is a function in another file that makes a fetch promise to an api and returns the value.
But the problem is  when I try to render the data and supply it as props to ImagesList component it gives Ojects are not valid error.

But seems to work fine when use the snippet.

1. So can somebody help me with rendering my data in a correct manner
2. Also the snippet contains data in json format and also the FetchApi when I checked in the console. So my question is why does it not give me the same results as the snippet if both the returned values are json array.

````
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import FetchApi from './imagesfile'
import {imagesList} from './spareFile'

console.log(imagesList)

const ImagesList = (props) => {
   console.log(props)
   return (
     <section>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>{props.img}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </section>
   )
}

// Snippet
// {imagesList.map((item) => {
//   const {id, img} = item;
//   return <ImagesList key={item.id} {...item} />
// })}


console.log(FetchApi().then(data => {console.log(data)}))

const Images = () => {
  console.log('hello')
  return(
    <section>
      <div>
          {FetchApi().then(data=>{
            {data.map((item) => {
              const { id, alt_description, urls } = item;
              return <ImagesList key = {item.id} {...item}/>
            })}
          })
        }
      </div>
      <h3>
      'Hello'
      </h3>
    </section>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Images />, document.getElementById('root'))```

Please need help.
````

Comment: FetchApi returns a promise, which indeed cannot be a child of a div element. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FetchApi()` inside of the `<div>` is technically a Promise. As an example, what your app is attempting to render is equivalent to:

```
  return <section>
    <div>
      {new Promise(/*some promise*/)}
    </div>
  </section>
```

You need to hold an empty array in state and update the component's state once the fetch has completed.  For example:

```
import ReactDOM, {useState, useEffect} from 'react-dom';


//...


const Images = () => {
  // this useState will initially set the value of items to an empty array
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]) 
  
  // this useEffect will be called once when the component mounts, 
  // fetch the data then call `setItems` setting the state for items, 
  // so it can be rendered with data below.
  useEffect(() => {
    FetchApi().then(data => {
      setItems(data)
    })
  }, [])
  
  return(
    <section>
      <div>
        {
          items.map((item) => {
            return <ImagesList key = {item.id} {...item}/>
          })
        }
      </div>
      <h3>
      'Hello'
      </h3>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! It works. I am new to react and haven't reached till hooks yet

Comment: No worries,  hooks are great once you get a feel for how they work, but there's a whole history of how they came to be so it can be a little unusual at first.